# Is it possible to make the reference point of an object move with the object in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Currently, as you can see in this picture the location of the reference point is fixed and independent of the object's location.

[image]

I would like to know if there is an option available to set a relative position for the reference point so that when the object is moved, the reference point moves with it (maintaining the distance between the object and the reference point)

Answer (score 1):

In the Free Transform, the reference point is moved with the object only if it is in the middle, or at one of eight "edge points".

If you need to move your object and then rotate it around that point, try to rotate it first and then move it.